# Are apples better than coffee to wake up?

Tags: coffee, apple

As you can see in [this google request answers](https://www.google.com/#q=apple+better+than+coffee&output=search&fp=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&cad=b), it is often said that eating an apple will wake you up better than coffee.

Really? Are there scientific proof about this? (I mean not only assumptions based on fruit composition)
Or is it a simplification?

Comment: Please cite actual websites instead of linking to google. It helps to get a sense of the actual claim.